# Help me generate this regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, validation

I have been trying to use regex but I cant seem to get it to work. I'm trying to use regex with the asp.net `RegularExpressionValidator`. What I want it to do is to basically disallow leading and trailing spaces only.

So,

```
"hello "                 // would not work.
"hello my name is"       // would work.
```

But in all my attempts it says bad input no matter what I put in.

Here is what I used:

```
^\s[a-z]+\s$
```

Can someone please provide one that works?

And also, what does it mean when someone says the regex returned a match?

Edit:

I have tried all the solutions in the thread and none of them work for me. Maybe it is something else wrong and not the regex? Heres is the relevant code:

```
                            <InsertItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox CssClass="tbUpdateSummary" TextMode="MultiLine" Text='<%# Bind("updateSummary") %>'
                                ID="tbUpdateSummaryInsert" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="valUpdateSummaryInsert1" runat="server" Display="None"
                                ControlToValidate="tbUpdateSummaryInsert" ErrorMessage="Update summary must not be empty.">
                            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ValidationExpression="^\s+|\s$" ID="valUpdateSummaryEdit2"
                                runat="server" Display="None" ControlToValidate="tbUpdateSummaryInsert"  ErrorMessage="Update summary must not contain leading or trailing spaces."> </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                            <%--Put c# code to validate length (max 200)--%>
                            <asp:CustomValidator></asp:CustomValidator>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
```

^[^\s].+[^\s]$ <======= This one actually works!!

Comment: I assume you don't want the leading / trailing spaces once you submit.  It might more sense, then, to just use `String.Trim()` on the text of your `TextBox` (rather than using Regex) when the submit occurs (like in an `btn_Click method`).  Just a thought

Comment: Would it be an acceptable solution to call trim() on any input?

Comment: Yes, but i need to learn how to do it with regex, because i need to test for other things aswell.

Comment: I found this tool very handy for learning regex: http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex it should match everything that don't have a white space at the start and end

```
^[^\s].+[^\s]$
```

Comment: +1, I bet that's exactly the problem he's running into,  good catch.

Comment: this is going to match only if both leading and trailing white space characters are present in the input. "hello " would not match.

Comment: Will break with preceeding/trailing double spaces

Comment: @spender always something you forget :) What do you think now?

Comment: No, it was fine the way it was.  All you care about is that the first and last character are not whitespace, and `^[^\s].+[^\s]$` guarantees that.  However, it also guarantees that there are at least three characters, and I don't see that in the OP's requirements. :/

Comment: reverted to ^[^\s].+[^\s]$ as this seems to be as good as my updated

Answer (score 2):

Given that the `RegularExpressionValidator` is looking for matches against good input rather than vice-versa:

The following regex will match anything that is not preceeded or followed by spaces:

```
^(?!\s+).+(?<!\s+)$
```

although the Trim option mentioned in the comments to the question seems like a more sensible way to proceed.

Comment: +1, but you don't need quantifiers inside the lookarounds; `(?!\s)` and `(?<!\s)` work fine.  If the first (or last) characters is whitespace, there's no point looking at any more, is there?

Comment: Yes indeed. Will leave in place so your comment makes sense!

Comment: Good idea.  This is a very common mistake, and while it might never have any *practical* impact, just thinking about it may "trick" one into a different perspective, leading unexpectedly to a deeper understanding.  And when it comes to understanding regexes, trust me, every little bit helps! ☺

Answer (score 0):

The regex validator is a positive test. You have three cases to test for

- input of length zero.
- input of length 1
- input of length > 1

Since you have a Required validator on the input control, the first case won't occur. The following vanilla regular expression should work:

```
^[^\s]([.\n]*[^\s])?$
```

You may read it as saying that valid input consists of:

- Start-of-line, followed by,
- Exactly 1 non-whitespace character, followed by
- An optional subexpression, consisting of

  - zero or more of any character, including LF (by default the metacharacter `.` matches any character **except** LF), followed by
  - exactly 1 nonwhitespace character,
    Followed by,
- end-of-line

Since you have a multi-line edit control in your example, use of `.*` in the middle instead of `[.\n]*` I use will result in the match terminating at the first LF character found. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes for details of .Net regular expression character classes.

[Edited to Note]

Testing this shows that for some reason, .Net doesn't like `[]` character classes containing `.` (or it treats it as a literal period character). This regular expression works:

```
^([^\s])((.|\n)*[^\s])$
```

But it allows for trailing line breaks.

However, this regular expression is better (for some definition of better). It (A) doesn't involve backtracking, and (B) won't allow trailing line breaks:

```
^[^\s]+(\s+[^\s]+)*$
```

- Start-of-line, followed by
- 1 or more non-whitespace characters, followed by
- zero or more repetitions of

  - 1 or more whitespace characters, followed by
  - 1 or more non-whitespace characters,
    Followed by,
- End-of-Line.

Good Luck!

Comment: It still flares up on any input except null. Why dont all of them work? It cant be that they are all wrong. I think i should just not use regex and validate everything server side....

Comment: @TheGateKeeper: see addendum above.